# Unknown exception at declaration and initalisation of a Class

Tags: c#, android, exception, xamarin.android

**The main Problem is completely different, please skip to the Edit**

I have an exception of an unknown type which doesn't even get thrown properly. Following Code provides the Context:

```
MMDataAccess.InitDemoDB();
MMDataAccess.InitInternalDB();
MMDataAccess.InitMaintDB();

try
{
    SQLiteToDBLib sqltdbl = new SQLiteToDBLib();
    sqltdbl.WriteToSQLite();
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    string message = ex.Message;
}
```

These are the very first lines of my first Activity in my app. The first 3 lines belong to my very own implementation of an in-memory database and are behaving nicely. The problem rises with the next two lines inside the try-block. The declaration and initalistation of the sqltdbl variable never happens. The constructor of SQLiteToDBLib looks like this:

```
public SQLiteToDBLib()
{
    msc = new MSConnection();
}
```

The MSConnection class doesn't even have a constructor (except for the default one of course).

As you can see i've tried to catch any exceptions, but without success. everything i can figure out is, that a exception is thrown because of the debugger going into the catch section while ignoring everything that has to do with "ex". Without breakpoints everything seems fine. Just without the call to WriteToSQLite which should create a .sqlite file on the external Memory.

What can I do to resolve this error? Is there anything i can catch except the default Exception?

**Edit:**

After some testing with commented code something interresting happened. I could step into commented code. Well not exactly the commented code, but the code that was there before my changes. Visual Studio somehow shows me the things, that are changed in the file, but is compiling the old code. Up to now i tried to rebuild, clean and build the project in various combinations, unload and reload the project, Restart Visual Studio and restart Windows. Nothing has changed so far. I Will now proceed to create a new .cs File With the exact same Code. I'm working with VS 2013 Community

Answer (score 0):

add static constructor to your SQLiteToDBLib class and perform all static objects initialization in it:

```
static SQLiteToDBLib()
{
   // initialize static members here
}
```

If this doesn't give you a clue, try enabling CLRE exceptions-break in visual-studio:

1. DEBUG
2. Exceptions
3. Check the 'Common Language Runtime Exceptions' option (under the 'Thrown' column)
4. Press OK

Restart your app and try again

Comment: Static constructor didn't work, and all Exceptions were enabled from the start. Now i have disabled all but CLRE. Nothing's changed.